# O que é o TOGAF?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, togaf

Me deparei com este termo TOGAF (*The Open Group Architecture Framework*) hoje em uma vaga relacionada a contratação de um "arquiteto de sistemas" em uma empresa de grande porte.

Nunca tinha ouvido alguém mencionar este termo até então e não encontrei muitas informações técnicas sobre. A princípio parece que existem diferentes níveis de "arquiteto" dentro do TOGAF e a última delas não está nem relacionada com a área técnica.

Sendo assim:

- O que é o TOGAF?
- Qual a importância em conhecer este *framework* ao pensar na arquitetura de um sistema de uma grande empresa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O que é o TOGAF?

O **T**he **O**pen **G**roup **A**rchitecture **F**ramework (TOGAF) nada mais é do que um framework para a criação de arquiteturas de softwares corporativos/grande porte. O TOGAF é mantido pelo [The Open Group](https://www.opengroup.org/), que é um consórcio global que tem como objetivo criar padrões e tecnologias abertos e neutras para ajudar organizações a alcançarem seus objetivos de negócio.

A ideia do TOGAF é fornecer um conjunto de recomendações, metodologias e diretrizes que auxiliem o desenvolvimento de arquiteturas complexas. Tudo isso pode ser encontrado na [especificação da TOGAF](https://publications.opengroup.org/standards/togaf/specifications/c182) (inglês). A especificação da TOGAF é dividida em 7 partes:

1. **Introdução**: Introdução aos conceitos de arquitetura corporativa, a abordagem TOGAF e definições de termos relevantes usados ​​no TOGAF.
2. **Architecture Design Method (ADM)**: Esta seção detalha o núcleo do TOGAF, o Architecture Design Method (ADM), que é a métodologia recomendada para a criação de arquiteturas.
3. **Diretrizes e técnicas da ADM**: Fornece diretrizes e técnicas para a aplicação do TOGAF e da ADM.
4. **Estrutura de conteúdo da Arquitetura**: Nesta parte, são fornecidas informações sobre a estrutura de conteúdo do TOGAF, incluindo os artefatos e produtos de arquitetura que fazem parte do processo.
5. **Continuidade e ferramentas empresariais**: Abrange os repositórios de arquitetura de uma empresa, incluindo a categorização e armazenamento de artefatos de arquitetura.
6. **Modelos de referência do TOGAF**: Explica vários modelos de referência de arquitetura, como o **TOGAF Foundation Architecture** e a **Integrated Information Infrastructure Reference Model (III-RM)**.
7. **Estrutura da arquitetura**: Fornece diretrizes sobre o estabelecimento e a operação de uma arquitetura corporativa dentro de uma empresa, incluindo processos, habilidades, funções e responsabilidades.

> Qual a importância em conhecer este framework ao pensar na arquitetura de um sistema de uma grande empresa?

A menos que uma empresa utilize estritamente o TOGAF, a única vantagem de conhecer este framework é que você terá mais ferramentas e técnicas para aplicar no desenvolvimento de arquiteturas de grandes empresas. O fato do TOGAF ser um framework implica que você nem sempre vai utilizar tudo o que ele tem, inclusive existem diversas críticas sobre o fato dele ser um pouco complicado de aplicar na prática.

No final das contas, é sempre bom conhecer as diversas metodologias e práticas para o desenvolvimento de arquiteturas existentes (*e.g.* **Architecture-centric Design Method (ACDM)**, **Attribute-driven Design (ADD)**, Design tático + estratégico, etc.) pois assim há grandes chances de você criar uma arquitetura robusta com o melhor de cada.

**Referências:**

- [Software Architect's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B3R2ZCX)
- [The Open Group](https://www.opengroup.org/)
- [The Open Group Architecture Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Open_Group_Architecture_Framework)